# Hatcher exercise 1.1.5

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification

> $\pi_1(X,x_0)=0$ for all $x_0\in X\Rightarrow$ Every map $S^1\to X$ is homotopic to a constant map.

The question is Hatcher exercise 1.1.5 and the solution is easy to find in MSE and Google. But first I want to check my solution is right

Proof. Let $f:S^1\to X$. Then by universal property of quotient, we get and induced map $f':I\to X$. Let $x_0=f'(0)=f'(1)$. Then $[f']\in\pi_1(X,x_0)$ so by assumption, $[f']=1$. Let $\pi:I\to I/\partial I$ be a quotient map. Since $f'\simeq_p C_{x_0}$, there is a path homotopy $H:I\times I\to X$ such that $H(-,0)=f\circ\pi$ and $H(-,1)=x_0$. Then again by the universal property,
$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} I\times I @>H>> X\\ @V\pi\times 1VV @V1VV\\ I/\partial I\times I @>\tilde{H}>> X \end{CD}$$
we get an induced map $\tilde{H}$. Now as the diagram commute, $f(\pi(x))=H(x,0)=\tilde{H}\circ(\pi\times 1)(x,0)=\tilde{H}(\pi(x),0)$ so that $\tilde{H}(x,0)=f$ and clearly $\tilde{H}(x,1)=\{\text{pt}\}$.

What I'm concern is the last part verifying $\tilde{H}(-,0)=f$. Is this OK? And once we consider a map $S^1\to X$ as $I\to X$ using the universal property, there's no more base point in this loop right?

In the same question they ask

> Deduce that a space $X$ is simply-connected iff all maps $S^1\to X$ are homotopic.

Proof. If $X$ is simply connected, then as $(c)\to (a)$ and $X$ is path-connected, all maps $S^1\to X$ are homotopic. If all maps $S^1\to X$ are homotopic, then in particular, they are nulhomotopic and if $S^1\to X$ is a constant map, then assumption also implies $X$ is path-connected. Hence as $(a)\to (c)$, $X$ is simply-connected.

Is this a valid proof?

Answer (score 1):

Your proof of: "$X$ is simply-connected iff. all maps $S^1\to X$ are homotopic" is fine, assuming the earlier stages of the exercise. One complication is that Hatcher says: "don't assume homotopies preserve basepoints for this exercise", but that's actually a necessary condition to describe equivalence classes in the fundamental group. Luckily the direction: "$\pi_1(X)=0\implies f:S^1\to X$ null homotopic" doesn't care about this point. Your proof of $\tilde H(-,0)=f$ was fine also.

I might say that the diagram chasing could be considered unnecessary here. Loops $I\to X$ and maps $S^1\to X$ are in clear bijection, that's all you need.

Maps $f:S^1\to X$ necessarily loop about some base point (pick $x_0=f(1)$, say) so the induced map $f':I\to X$ is a loop in the sense of a path whose endpoints are the same, just fine. I'm not sure what you mean by "there's no basepoint in the loop, right?" since $f'(0)=f'(1)$ would be considered the basepoint by standard conventions.